# Are there any objects without __proto__ properties?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning the prototype chain mechanism of JavaScript, I am curious whether there is an object without the `__proto__` property?

Comment: `Object.create(null)`, for example. Please note that [`__proto__` is deprecated](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Answer (score 4):

> I am currently learning the prototype chain mechanism of JavaScript

For that purpose, the `__proto__` property is largely just a distraction. The important thing is really the [`[[Prototype]]` internal slot](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots). That's what holds a reference to the object's prototype (or `null` if the object doesn't have a prototype object). The [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is just an accessor property for the value of `[[Prototype]]` internal slot, and it's really only there for backward compatibility with old code. In modern JavaScript, to get the prototype of an object, use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf). (And to set it on an existing object — which you should normally avoid doing — you'd use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).)

> I am curious whether there is an object without the `__proto__` property?

Yes. The `__proto__` property is defined by `Object.prototype`, so any object that doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` (directly or indirectly) has no `__proto__` property *(well, unless one is created some other way by custom code)*. But that doesn't mean it doesn't have the `[[Prototype]]` internal slot, and doesn't mean it doesn't have a prototype object. **All** ordinary objects have the `[[Prototype]]` internal slot. It may contain `null` (indicating that the object has no prototype), but the object has the slot.

Here's an example:

```js
// An object inheriting from `Object.prototype` (directly)
const objectWith1 = {};
objectWith1.hello = () => { console.log("Hello"); };
// Another object inheriting from `Object.prototype` (indirectly)
const objectWith2 = Object.create(objectWith1);
// An object NOT inheriting from `Object.prototype`
const objectWithout1 = Object.create(null);
objectWithout1.hi = () => { console.log("Hi"); };
// Another object NOT inheriting from `Object.prototype`
const objectWithout2 = Object.create(objectWithout1);

console.log("__proto__" in objectWith1);    // true
console.log("__proto__" in objectWith2);    // true
objectWith1.hello();                        // "Hello"
objectWith2.hello();                        // "Hello"
console.log("__proto__" in objectWithout1); // false
console.log("__proto__" in objectWithout2); // false
objectWithout1.hi();                        // "Hi"
objectWithout2.hi();                        // "Hi"
```

In that snippet, neither `objectWithout1` nor `objectWithout2` has the `__proto__` property, but they both still have the `[[Prototype]]` internal slot. For `objectWithout1`, that slot contains `null` because `objectWithout1` doesn't have a prototype. For `objectWithout2`, that slot contains `objectWithout1`, because `objectWithout1` is the prototype of `objectWithout2` (that's where `objectWithout2` gets its `hi` method from).

Here's a rough sketch of the object graph from the snippet:

```
                                                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
Object.prototype>−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>|   (object)     |
                                             /   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     /    | get __proto__  |>−−>(function)
objectWith1>−−−−−−+−>|    (object)    |    /     | set __proto__  |>−−>(function)
                 /   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   /      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 |   | [[Prototype]]  |>−+
                 |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  |
              +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
objectWith2>−>|    (object)    |  |
              +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
              | [[Prototype]]  |>−+
              +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
objectWithout1>−−−+−>|       (object)      |
                 /   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 |   | [[Prototype]]: null |
                 |   | hi                  |>−−>(function)
                 |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                     |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
objectWithout2>−>|    (object)    |  |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                 | [[Prototype]]  |>−+
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: thank you for your reply，Does objectWithout2 have no __proto__ accessor property, is it because objectWithout1 does not have __proto__ accessor property?

Comment: @andrewyin - Right! `objectWithProto` has it because it inherits from `Object.prototype`, which has it. `objectWithout1` doesn't have it because it doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` (or anything else, its prototype is `null`). `objectWithout2` doesn't have it because it doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` either (it inherits from `objectWithout1`, and `objectWithout1` doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`). *(This is a corrected version of an earlier comment.)*

Comment: I've added a second "with" object because it occurred to me that having one "with" and two "without" might be confusing.

Comment: I would like to ask whether the get __proto__ and set __proto__ in Object.prototype are related to the _ _proto_ _ of other objects?

Comment: @andrewyin - I just draw it "by hand" in my text editor. Yes, `get __proto__` and `set __proto__` are the accessor property that objects inherit.